# Ember- Setting properties to default state after a successful save

Tags: ember.js

I've got a pretty long form containing 10+ dynamically populated forms

Those are some of the properties

```
  metadata : {},
  creators : [],
  subjects : [],
  contributors : [],
  dates : [],
  identifiers : [],
  descriptions : [],
  geolocations : [],
  alternateidentifiers : [],
  sizes : [],
  formats : [],
  rights : [],
  files : [],
  newMetaDataRecord : null,

  // Choices from backend
  resourceTypesGeneral : null,
  contributorsType : null,
  dateType : null,
  relatedIdentifTypes : null,
  relationType : null,
  descriptionType : null,

  //BACKEND errorLOG array
  errorMessageObject : [],

  // Validations
  invalidCreatorsList : [],
  validCreators : false,

  invalidSubjectsList : [],
  validSubjects : true,

  invalidContributorsList : [],
  validContributors : true,

  invalidDatesList : [],
  validDates : true,

  invalidIdentifiersList : [],
  validIdentifiers : true,

  invalidDescriptionsList : [],
  validDescriptions : true,

  invalidGeosList : [],
  validGeos : true,

  invalidalternateIdentifiersList : [],
  validAlternates : true,

  invalidSizesList : [],
  validSizes : true,

  invalidFormatsList : [],
  validFormats : true,

  invalidRightsList : [],
  validRights : true,
```

I used to have a function called

```
setFormToDefaultState : function(){
    this.set('metadata', this.createEmptyMetaData());
    this.set('metadata.resource_type', this.createEmptyResourceType());
    this.createEmptyCreator();
  },
```

Which is similar to Initialize

```
init : function(){
    this._super();

    this.set('metadata', this.createEmptyMetaData());
    this.set('metadata.resource_type', this.createEmptyResourceType());
    this.createEmptyCreator();
  },
```

That kind of did work when i had less properties, but now there's almost 30 properties to set default and i wonder if there's an easier solution for this. Doing it in route does not work either, since on reNavigation fields would be lost (already filled in data).

So is there a function to reset.all() ?

Current solution

```
var arProperties = ["creators", "subjects", "contributors", "dates", "identifiers", "descriptions", "geolocations", "alternateidentifiers", "sizes", "formats", "rights", "files", "titles", "taxons", "invalidTaxonsList", "invalidCreatorsList", "invalidSubjectsList", "invalidContributorsList", "invalidDatesList", "invalidIdentifiersList", "invalidDescriptionsList", "invalidGeolocationsList", "invalidAlternateidentifiersList", "invalidSizesList", "invalidFormatsList", "invalidRightsList", "invalidTitlesList"];
    arProperties.forEach(function(arProperty) { 
      self.set(arProperty, []); 
    });
    var trueProperties  = ["formInvalid", "validTaxons", "validSubjects", "validContributors", "validDates", "validIdentifiers", "validDescriptions", "validGeolocations", "validAlternateidentifiers", "validSizes", "validFormats", "validRights"];
    trueProperties.forEach(function(trueProperty){
      self.set(trueProperty, true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this by setting a property on route . So if you enter the route for the first time, model gets loaded, then the property changes and on the second visit to route the "return" gets called. This way your inputs stay the same and u can still easily reset all properties.

```
import RouteMixin from 'appkit/misc/routemixin';
export default Ember.Route.extend(Ember.SimpleAuth.AuthenticatedRouteMixin, RouteMixin, {
  model : function(){
  var self = this;

    if(Ember.isNone(self.get('controller.routeHasBeenLoaded'))){
         return Ember.RSVP.hash({

            invalidTaxonsList : [],
            validTaxons : true,

            invalidCreatorsList : [],
            validCreators : false,

            invalidSubjectsList : [],
            validSubjects : true,

            invalidContributorsList : [],
            validContributors : true,

            invalidDatesList : [],
            validDates : true,

          });
    } else {
        return;
    } 
  },
 }

});
```

Controller

```
init : function(){
 this._super();
 this.set('routeHasBeenLoaded', true)
}
```